# Integer output formatting. what is the analogue of printf(%.3x)?

Tags: c++, formatting, iostream

I did my googling for this thing, but haven't found the answer.
I want to find analogue for output formatting in plain C. To be more specific, something which works similar to `printf(%.3x)`
Probably, it could be done using manipulators. However, the code

`cout << showbase << setfill('0') << setw(5) << hex << 19 << endl;`

gives me `00x13` instead of desired `0x013`.

P.S. Sorry, I don't have the Boost library, so this is not a solution..

Comment: unless this is an academic question.. you can still use printf as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizing `internal`:

```
cout << showbase << setw(5) << setfill('0') << internal << hex << 19 << endl;
```

Comment: Oh, this is probably best! didn't know that `internal` would work in this case

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "0x" << setfill('0') << setw(3) << hex << 19 << endl;
```

Note that `setfill` and `hex` alter the state of the stream for subsequent output as well, unlke `setw` which just affects the next output.

Comment: An explanation as to why `0x` in preference to `showbase` answers the problem would get a +1 from me.

Comment: @acraig5075: because showbase apparently does not work as expected?

Answer (score -1):

```
char buffer[40];
snprintf(buffer, 40, "%.3x", 19);
std::cout << buffer;
```